# Can't get UIScrollView to be recognized inside of UITableViewCell, nil error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

So when I run my code it keeps erroring out in the awakeFromNib function. It doesn't seem to recognize my UIScrollView which I have defined from an IBOutlet. Here is my UITableViewCell code:

```
import UIKit

class ItemDetailsCell: UITableViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var centerImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var labelBlack: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var heading: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var body: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableScrollView: UIScrollView!


    var pageImages: [UIImage] = []
    var pageViews: [UIImageView?] = []

    static var parentView : ItemDetailsVC!;


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        //tableScrollView.delegate = self;
        var scrollViewWidth = ItemDetailsCell.parentView.scrollViewWidth
        var scrollViewHeight = ItemDetailsCell.parentView.scrollViewHeight

        if let tableCheck = ItemDetailsCell.parentView.scrollImages as [Dictionary<Int,UIImage>]? {
            if ItemDetailsCell.parentView.scrollImages.count > 0 {
                for var subviewCounter: Int = 0; subviewCounter <= tableCheck.count; subviewCounter++ {
                    for scrollImage in tableCheck {
                        if let imgToInsert = scrollImage[subviewCounter] as UIImage? {
                            let viewWidth = CGFloat(subviewCounter-1)
                            let imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth * viewWidth, 0, scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))
                            imgTwo.image = imgToInsert
                            imgTwo.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                            imgTwo.userInteractionEnabled = true
                            var gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tappedOnImage:")
                            var pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "pinchedImage:")
                            imgTwo.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
                            imgTwo.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
                            tableScrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)
                        } else {
                            println("no match")
                        }

                    }
                }
```

So I have a UITableView in my other ViewController and it has 2 prototype cells, one with the UIScrollView and the other with just text labels. Here is my code for the UITableView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {

        let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ItemDetailsCell

        myCell.centerImage.image = mainImage

            myCell.heading.text = detailsHeadings[indexPath.row]
            let headingString = detailsHeadings[indexPath.row]
            myCell.body.text = details[headingString]

        println("Label Height")
        println(myCell.labelBlack.frame.height)
        myCell.tableScrollView.frame = scrollViewOrigFrame

        return myCell

        } else {
```

The error I am getting is when it loads I am getting an error that is "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on the tableScrollView variable.

Any idea why I would be getting this? I probably am not doing the best way to do a scrolling image viewer inside of a table but I couldn't find much info on that.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the error on the line

```
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ItemDetailsCell
```

It is unwrapping the optional value but it found it as `nil`. Is the cell with identifier `Cell` registered on the tableView?

Comment: I am getting the error on the line `tableScrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)`

Comment: That means either of the two is nil. But is looks like imgTwo is set moments before that. Did you remember to attach the tableScrollView from your XIB/Storyboard?